Can I Upgrade TinyMCE to Version 7 While Keeping Orchard CMS at Version 1.9.1?
I'm currently maintaining a project that uses Orchard CMS version 1.9.1. For the rich text editor, we're using TinyMCE, specifically an older version (4.1.6). Due to security vulnerabilities, I'd like to upgrade TinyMCE to version 7.
My questions are:

Compatibility: Is it possible to upgrade TinyMCE to version 7 while keeping Orchard CMS at version 1.9.1? Are there any known compatibility issues between TinyMCE 7 and Orchard CMS 1.9.1?

Custom Plugins: Our setup includes custom plugins like mediapicker and medialibrary which are integrated with TinyMCE. Will these custom plugins likely need significant modifications to work with TinyMCE 7?

Configuration Changes: What are the key changes in the configuration of TinyMCE from version 4 to version 7 that I should be aware of?

Steps and Best Practices: What are the recommended steps and best practices to follow when upgrading TinyMCE in an existing Orchard CMS project?


Current Setup:

Orchard CMS Version: 1.9.1

TinyMCE Version: 4.1.6

Custom Plugins: mediapicker, medialibrary


Any insights, experiences, or guidance on this upgrade path would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I've checked GitHub and Stack Overflow, but I can't find any indication that it's possible to update TinyMCE from version 4 with Orchard CMS, much less upgrading all the way to version 7.
